# Concatenate cells between dynamic start and end row with custom formulas

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

The below code will add the cells in column B between modalOpen and modalClose into a single cell in column C.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(B2:B<>"", IF(A2:A="modalOpen",
"♥"&B2:B&"♦"&B2:B&" with", IF(A3:A="modalClose", "& <"&B2:B&">", "
<"&B2:B&">,")), ),,999^99), "♥")), "♦"), 2, 0)), ">, & ", "> & ")))
```

[image: examplePage]

The below code is used to put cells together with text from the Test Names sheet.

```
=IF(B21=testNameButton, CONCATENATE(A21, testNameButtonCodeBlock0, C21, testNameButtonCodeBlock1), 
IF(B21=testNameModal, CONCATENATE(A21, testNameModalCodeBlock0, C21, testNameModalCodeBlock1, REGEXREPLACE(C21,"\s","")),
```

[image: testsPage]

[image: dataPage]

The aim is to combine these two formulas together so that I can add the `ARRAYFORMULA` into the TestNames sheet.

**EDIT:**
I have added the two but have an issue when there is not a modalOpen directly underneath a modalClose. I also need to remove the modalOpen from the code.

```
=IF(B26=testNameButton, CONCATENATE(A26, testNameButtonCodeBlock0, C26, testNameButtonCodeBlock1), 
IF(testNameModal=B26, CONCATENATE(A26, testNameModalCodeBlock0, C26, testNameModalCodeBlock1, ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C26, 
SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(C26:C<>"", 
IF(B26:B="modalOpen", "♥"&C26:C&"♦"&C26:C, 
IF(B27:B="modalClose", "& <"&C26:C&">", "<"&C26:C&">,")), )
,,999^99), "♥")), "♦"), 2, 0)), ">, & ", "> & ")))),  
IF(B26=testNameTextBox, CONCATENATE(A26, testNameTextBoxCodeBlock0, REGEXREPLACE(C26,"\s",""), testNameTextBoxCodeBlock1, C26, testNameTextBoxCodeBlock2), 
IF(B26=testNameDropDown, CONCATENATE(A26, testNameDropDownCodeBlock0, REGEXREPLACE(C26,"\s",""), testNameDropDownCodeBlock1, C26, testNameDropDownCodeBlock2), 
IF(OR(B26="page", B26="", B26="modalField - textBox", B26="modalField - dropDown", B26="modalClose"), "")))))
```

[image]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?

Comment: Please access link in EDIT. Let me know if any problems.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Please try again with this 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pKNE4I0Z041pgxvM3mZuj7W39D4rJbuD7kgeRoV-6s8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### here is the fixed first formula in desired format:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IF(C2:C<>"", 
 IF(B2:B="modalOpen", "♥"&A2:A&"♦step("""&A2:A&" Fill in "&C2:C&" with", 
 IF(B3:B="modalClose", "& <"&C2:C&">"",♣", "<"&C2:C&">,")), )
 ,,999^99), "(♥.*)"), "♥")), 
 "(.*)♣"), "♦"), ">, & ", "> & " ), 2, 0))&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IF(C2:C<>"", 
 IF(B2:B="modalOpen", "♥"&A2:A&"♦ async (", 
 IF(B3:B="modalClose", C2:C&") => {await waitFor(1000),♣", C2:C&",")), )
 ,,999^99), "(♥.*)"), "♥")), 
 "(.*)♣"), "♦"), " ( ", " ("), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

#### and here is the joint formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IF(C2:C<>"", 
 IF(B2:B="modalOpen", "♥"&A2:A&"♦step("""&A2:A&" Fill in "&C2:C&" with", 
 IF(B3:B="modalClose", "& <"&C2:C&">"",♣", "<"&C2:C&">,")), )
 ,,999^99), "(♥.*)"), "♥")), 
 "(.*)♣"), "♦"), ">, & ", "> & " ), 2, 0))&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IF(C2:C<>"", 
 IF(B2:B="modalOpen", "♥"&A2:A&"♦ async (", 
 IF(B3:B="modalClose", C2:C&") => {await waitFor(1000),♣", C2:C&",")), )
 ,,999^99), "(♥.*)"), "♥")), 
 "(.*)♣"), "♦"), " ( ", " ("), 2, 0), 
 IF(B2:B=testNameButton, A2:A&testNameButtonCodeBlock0&C2:C&testNameButtonCodeBlock1, 
 IF(B2:B=testNameModal,  A2:A&testNameModalCodeBlock0&C2:C&testNameModalCodeBlock1&
 REGEXREPLACE(C2:C, "\s", ), ))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Looks brilliant and works really well, one thing I noticed though is that column D row 33 "Team Name" has a space. It needs all spaces to be removed.

Comment: @TristanC you can fix it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d9vW.png

Comment: How might I modify this if I have just the one modalField between modalOpen and modalClose?

Current output 
`16-075 Fill in Add Section with & <Name>`

Desired output
`16-075 Fill in Add Section with <Name>`

Comment: you can wrap it into substitute like: `...SUBSTITUTE(..., "with &", "with ")`

Comment: I seem to error when I try this... https://imgur.com/gallery/EI5r6OF